# How to abort python fabric run command?

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

```
run("if [ -d data.bak ];then mv data.bak data;fi;")
sudo('....')
sudo('')
```

I am using fabric deploy for my web project. I want to find a way that will stop the rest of the execution of the command, if it doesn't find the data.bak directory. Any way to achieve this in fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a contribute api in `fabric.contrib.files` import.